# C# AWS S3 - List objects created before or after a certain time

Tags: c#, amazon-s3

I'm working with the `ListObjectsRequest` and `ListObjectsV2Request` and can't seem to find a way within the request to specify a timestamp to either retrieve objects created before or after a specific timestamp.

Is there a way to do this using the AWSSDK?

If not, is there a way to do this using a direct RESTful request to S3 (and if so is there an example)?  I unfortunately cannot use the AWS CLI in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A review of the low-level API (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/v2-RESTBucketGET.html) shows there are no ways to filter by last modified date.  How many files are in the single S3 bucket?  Unless it's more than, say, 10,000 files, why not just get a list of all the files and then filter the list on the client side?  Unless it's a LOT of files, getting just the list of files is not a lot of data to transfer.

Comment: Hi @Nick Ganju, it could be thousands to hundreds of thousands.  Thanks for your response, I'll accept this as the answer since it references the low-level API.

Comment: Similar to a a local filesystem folder, it's probably not a good idea to have hundreds of thousands of files in a single bucket/folder.  You could make sub-buckets by date and store the files in those, and just query the buckets you want, i.e. name your buckets s3://mybucket/2019-06-11/ and then search by the prefix.

Comment: @joelc If you have a large quantity of files in the Amazon S3 bucket, you could consider using [Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html), which can provide a daily CSV file of all objects in the bucket (charges apply).

Comment: By 27/10/2020, it seems that it is still a valid answer that it is not possible to filter by modified date of content. Will try Amazon S3 Inventory if it can fix our problem.

Comment: Sometimes we have no control over which AWS buckets are used, to everybody saying "just change the bucket"...